# Commutativity and Jordan Decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, jordan-normal-form

Apologies in advance if my formatting is bad.

I'm working on the following problem and I've run into a bit of a wall.

> Let $ V $ be a vector space over an algebraically closed field $ \mathcal{F} $. Let $ T \in End(V) $ with Jordan decomposition $ T = D + N $ where $ D $ is diagonalizable and $ N $ is nilpotent. Prove that $ S \in End(V) $ commutes with $ T $ if and only if $ S $ commutes with $ D $ and $ S $ commutes with $ N $.

Proving the reverse direction is very easy. If $ S $ commutes with $ D $ and $ N $, then

$$
 ST = S(D + N) = SD + SN = DS + NS = (D + N)S = TS
$$

So $ T $ and $ S $ commute.

Proving the forward direction is more difficult. If $ T $ and $ S $ commute, then

$$
 ST = TS \Rightarrow SD - DS = NS - SN
$$

At this point, I'm not sure how to proceed. I've tried messing around with the minimal polynomial of $ T $ but was unable to make something of it. I've also tried applying the Jordan decomposition to $ S $ itself, but this didn't help either. I feel like I'm missing some fundamental property about diagonalizable and nilpotent operators that I need to complete this proof. Any suggestions or pointers on how to proceed from here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The way you construct $D$ and $N$ from $T$, you see that $D$ and $N$ are polynomials in $T$.

Comment: Right, so this means that $ D $ and $ N $ commute. Is it necessary to use any other properties of $ D $ and $ N $, or is the fact that they commute with each other enough to show that they each commute with $ S $?

Comment: If $S$ commutes with $T$, then $S$ commutes with any polynomial in $T$.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! For some reason, I had the misconception that this would only be the case if $ S $ too was a polynomial in $ T $.